# Extract an embedded xml file from a DICOM using MyDICOM

Tags: c#, dicom

I am receiving a DICOM image with an embedded xml result file. I can find the Tag where the xml should be located using DVTk, but I have not been able to figure out how to extract it using MyDICOM.

I cannot share the DICOM as it contains proprietary information, and I do not have permission. I am hoping that there is someone out there who has experience working with MyDICOM who might be able to help.

I doubt posting code that I have will help anyone, but I'll do it anyway:

```
if (element.ValueRepresentation.ToString().ToLower().Equals("ob"))
{
    DeferredStream stream = element.Get(0) as DeferredStream;
    MyDicom.StreamReader reader = new MyDicom.StreamReader(stream, dicom.MetaData.Tsn);
    reader.UseDeferredStream = true;
    reader.EnforceEvenByteSizeElement = dicom.EnforceEvenByteSize;
    if (dicom.PrivateDictionary != null)
        reader.PrivateDictionary = dicom.PrivateDictionary;
    //object embedded = reader.Deserialize(this.dataSetStartTag, this.dataSetEndTag);
 }
```

I'm not sure if this code will actually work, and even if it does, I don't have the start and end tags. I have not provided much information, so I don't expect much, but I would love to get even a nudge in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is NOT the correct way to do it, but it was the only way I was able to find without proper documentation for MyDICOM. I loaded the stream into a string, and then searched for the information that I needed.

```
//  Set up the stream
object elem = element.Get(0);
if (elem is DeferredStream)
     stream = elem as DeferredStream;
else if (elem is MemoryStream)
     stream = elem as MemoryStream;

//  Set up the stream reader
reader = new MyDicom.StreamReader(stream, dicom.MetaData.Tsn);
reader.UseDeferredStream = (elem is DeferredStream);
reader.EnforceEvenByteSizeElement = dicom.EnforceEvenByteSize;
if (dicom.PrivateDictionary != null)
     reader.PrivateDictionary = dicom.PrivateDictionary;

//  Read the Stream into a String
byte[] read = reader.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length));
String data = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(read);
int start = data.IndexOf("<PatientData>");
int length = data.Substring(start).IndexOf("</PatientData>") + 15;

if (start > 0 && length > 0)
     result = data.Substring(start, length);
else
     result = "";
```

I'm worried about the speed and accuracy of this method, so would still welcome the correct way if anyone knows it. Otherwise, I will mark this as complete.